# My query string containing forward slashes will only take values before the slash (i.e. ?id=foo/bar will give id="foo")

Tags: mod-rewrite

When it comes to mod_rewrite, I'm a total newbie. My code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\s/(product)/\?id=([^\s]+) [NC]
# Strip the query and redirect permanently
RewriteRule  ^(product)  /$1/%3?   [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
# Map internally to the original request
RewriteRule  ^(product)/([^/]+)/?  /$1/?id=$2  [L,NC]
```

**What it does**

`example.com/products?id={string}` =rewritten=> `example.com/products/{string}` which contains `id={string}`

**The problem**
It treats slashes as the end of a query string which I don't want. I want it to treat `{string}` as a string until we hit a `&` character. Is this possible? If so how can this be done?

E.g. `For "id=sdf/sdf/wer/sfd" print_r($_GET['id']) would be "sdf/sdf/wer/sfd"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line: `RewriteRule  ^(product)/([^/]+)/?  /$1/?id=$2  [L,NC]`

Should be `RewriteRule  ^(product)/([^\s]+[^/]+)/?  /$1/?id=$2  [L,NC]`